# How to combine PathPrefixStrip with Redirect:Regex?

Tags: traefik

My configuration looks like this:

**frontend**

```
traefik.frontend.rule=Host:my.domain;PathPrefixStrip:/mypath/
```

**traefik param**

```
--entrypoints="Name:http Address::80 Redirect.EntryPoint:https Redirect.Regex:http://my.domain/(.*)$ Redirect.Replacement:https://my.domain/$1 Redirect.Permanent:true"
```

My goal is to redirect HTTP requests on a given path to its HTTPS endpoint. However, the path prefix removal seems to be happening **before** the "main" redirect.regex/replacement logic, which is breaking some requests. For example:

```
http://my.domain/mypath/v1/foo
```

Will become:

```
https://my.domain/v1/foo
```

While I expected it to be:

```
https://my.domain/mypath/v1/foo
```

Anyway to workaround this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Please note that `regex` and `replacement` do not have to be set in the redirect structure if an `entrypoint` is defined for the redirection (they will not be used in this case).

https://docs.traefik.io/v1.5/configuration/entrypoints/#redirect-http-to-https

Note also that `Redirect.Permanent:true` come in 1.6

Try something like that:

```
--entrypoints="Name:http Address::80 Redirect.Regex:http://my.domain/(.*)$ Redirect.Replacement:https://my.domain/mypath/$1 Redirect.Permanent:true"
```

Comment: Nope, I get the exact same results

Comment: I'm using traefik 1.6-rc5 (just started my project and it is not critical, so I'm giving it a shot)